# How do I use NodaTime to string format with a Culture's ShortDatePattern?

Tags: c#, nodatime

With a C# DateTime and Culture I can format to a string with:

```
DateTime exampleDate = DateTime.Now;
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
String datetimeFormat = exampleDate.ToString(culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern));
```

How do I achieve the same with NodaTime? I've tried combinations along the lines of (doesn't compile - ToString requires two parameters with NodaTimef):

```
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["fr-FR"];
ZonedDateTime nowZonedDateTime = new ZonedDateTime(Instant.FromDateTimeUtc(DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime()), timeZone);
String nodaFormat = nowZonedDateTime.LocalDateTime.ToString(culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern));
```

I've also tried combinations around the documentation which indicates I need to use "d" to format to short date (this throws an exception):

```
String nodaFormat = nowZonedDateTime.LocalDateTime.ToString("d", culture));
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Please edit the question to show what the compile-time error is in your first attempt, and what the exception is in your second attempt. (I'd also strongly advise using `IClock` instead of `DateTime.Now` - with `ZonedClock` involved as well, it becomes much simpler...)

Comment: Thanks Jon, I've updated the question hopefully is clearer. I've not used IClock before, I will see if I can find some documentation. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, there isn't a timezone with the ID of `fr-FR` in TZDB, did you mean `Europe/Paris`?

Secondly, `ToString` actually accepts 2 parameters - a pattern string and an `IFormatProvider`, which can be your `CultureInfo`. So you're very nearly there - you just need to pass in the `culture` as the second argument:

```
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["Europe/Paris"];
ZonedDateTime nowZonedDateTime = new ZonedDateTime(Instant.FromDateTimeUtc(DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime()), timeZone);
String nodaFormat = nowZonedDateTime.LocalDateTime.ToString(culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern, culture);
// nodaFormat would be "27/12/2019"
```